# Cordova Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I've been trying to effectively port an html multiple choice quiz that I wrote over to a mobile platform for further development, but I find that my Javascript isn't working properly with something, be it Cordova, or the BlueStacks emulator.

All of the questions are multiple choice, with different score values for each button, in index.html.

```
<p class="question">Question 1</p><br/>       

<div class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">answer 1</label><br/><br/>          
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">answer 2</label><br/><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">answer 3</label><br/><br/>                  
</div>

<button id = "finishbutton">Finish</button>
```

Each Radio button corresponds to a value in an array in the JS, which is then added to a total score variable, named totscore, through the function getScore(), which should be triggered by finishbutton.

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    document.getElementById("finishbutton").addEventListener("click", getScore);
    }

};

var totscore = 0;
var scores1 = [0, 1, 2];

function getScore(){
    if(document.getElementById("q1a").checked){
        totscore += scores1[0];
    } else if(document.getElementById("q1b").checked){
        totscore += scores1[1];
    } else if(document.getElementById("q1c").checked){
        totscore += scores1[2];
    }

    alert("Your score is " + totscore + ".")
}
```

Since Cordova already has the index.js, index.html, and index.css linked, I'm not sure why the function isn't running when finishbutton is tapped/clicked.

Comment: Have you called `app.onDeviceReady` ?

Comment: Is there anywhere specific that I'm supposed to do that? Cordova's functions are still pretty new to me.

Comment: NO...Not at all... Try `document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady)`

Comment: Where should I add it?

Comment: I read it wrong... Add `app.initialize()` after `var app`...

Comment: Did that and updated. Emulated again and ran through. The function still doesn't seem to be triggering.

Comment: Add some `alert()` and test.. Any errors ?

Comment: In adding alerts down the chain of everything, I've found out that deviceready is not firing. I have cordova.js linked successfully, so I know that's not the issue. I'll look at deviceready questions to see If I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you testing this in mobile device ?

Comment: Emulating in BlueStacks.

Comment: Mistyped `app.initialize()`. Problem is null. Thanks for your help, @Rayon.

Comment: Always use IDE... I go with Jetbrains. Choose any but it is must... To err is human..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `app.initialize();` after the `var app` declaration

Comment: I added app.initialize(); but the function still isn't triggering.